# Parsing a Complex Number from Scratch

Tags: parsing, haskell, alternative-functor

Given a data type `data CI = CI Int Int`, representing a complex number, I want to build a parser for CI that can convert `"a"` to `CI a 0` and `"(a,b)"` to `CI a b`. For example, I want a function `parseCI` such `runParser parseCI "(1,2)"` returns the value `[(CI 1 2, "")]` (ideally, but something similar is fine). I also want to make CI an instance of `read`.

I would like to do this using functions and definitions from the code below (basically, without anything advanced, like Parsec), but I'm not sure where to start. Some starting code to set me on the right track and/or a hint would be helpful. I'm not looking for a full answer, as I'd like to figure that out myself.

```
module Parser where
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> [(a,String)] }

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy f = Parser $ \s -> case s of
    [] -> []
    a:as -> [(a,as) | f a]

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char = satisfy . (==)

string :: String -> Parser String
string str = Parser $ \s -> [(t,u) | let (t,u) = splitAt (length str) s, str == t]

instance Functor Parser where
    fmap f p = Parser $ \s ->
        [ (f a,t)
        | (a,t) <- runParser p s
        ]

instance Applicative Parser where
    pure a = Parser $ \s -> [(a,s)]
    af <*> aa = Parser $ \s ->
        [ (f a,u) 
        | (f,t) <- runParser af s
        , (a,u) <- runParser aa t
        ]

instance Alternative Parser where
    empty = Parser $ \s -> []
    p1 <|> p2 = Parser $ (++) <$> runParser p1 <*> runParser p2`

instance Monad Parser where
    return = pure
    ma >>= f = Parser $ \s ->
       [ (b,u) 
       | (a,t) <- runParser ma s
       , (b,u) <- runParser (f a) t
       ]

instance MonadPlus Parser where
    mzero = empty
    mplus = (<|>)
```

Comment: Technically, that's a Gauss number /nitpick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably already seen it, but in case you haven't: [Monadic Parsing in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf) sets up parsing like this.

Since you have two different ways of parsing `CI`, you might want to approach this as two problems: make one parser `parseCI1` that parses `"a"` to `CI a 0` and make another parser `parseCI2` that parses `"(a,b)"` to `CI a b`. Then, you can combine these into one with

```
parseCI = parseCI1 <|> parseCI2
```

For both of these subparsers, you will need some way of parsing integers: `parseInt :: Parser Int`. When making `parseInt`, you will likely want to use some combination of `satisfy`, [`isDigit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit), [`read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read), and possibly [`some`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:some) (depending on how you go about solving this).

---

Making `CI` an instance of read is a bit more straightforward once you have `parseCI` done:

```
instance Read CI where
  readsPrec _ = runParser parseCI
```